# Как установить зависимость uvloop на windows?

Tags: python, windows, pip

```
pip install uvloop
```

вот такая ошибка, винда не поддерживается, значит совсем никак или есть какая то хитрость?

```
Collecting uvloop
  Using cached uvloop-0.17.0.tar.gz (2.3 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\evyrf\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2ww03jfd\uvloop_702837f4a8894afc8e7363a5b717d90a\setup.py", line 8, in <module>
          raise RuntimeError('uvloop does not support Windows at the moment')
      RuntimeError: uvloop does not support Windows at the moment
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: Если прямо пишут, что не поддерживается, значит прямо сейчас фактически никак. В будущем возможно доработают. Если есть соответствующие навыки: смотрите код библиотеки, дорабатываете, делаете pull-request в репозиторий, разработчики принимают, выкладывают на pypi, все радуются.